# 404 error message through Jersey rest api to access neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, jersey

I am trying to access a neo4j database through the Jersey rest API, and I got the following error:

```
1 * Client out-bound request
1 > POST http://localhost:7474//db/data/cypher
1 > Accept: application/json
1 > Authorization: Basic bmVvNGo6d29yaw==
{"query":"MATCH (n1)-[r]->(n2) RETURN r, n1, n2 LIMIT 25"}
1 * Client in-bound response
1 < 404
1 < Server: Jetty(9.2.22.v20170606)
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
1 < Content-Length: 0
1 < Date: Sat, 03 Feb 2018 23:48:00 GMT
1 < 
POST http://localhost:7474//db/data/cypher returned a response status of 404 Not Found
```

I can test that the query is valid and successful if I don't issue the query through the rest api. What might be the issue?

```
public static String SERVER_ROOT_URI = "http://localhost:7474//db/data/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = Client.create();
        client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));
        client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("neo4j", "test"));
        WebResource cypher = client.resource(SERVER_ROOT_URI + "cypher");

        String request = "{\"query\":\"MATCH (n1)-[r]->(n2) RETURN r, n1, n2 LIMIT 25\"}";
        ClientResponse cypherResponse = cypher.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, request);
        cypherResponse.close();
        System.out.println(cypherResponse);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the URL is right? Look at the double slash. Is that supposed to be there?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, you are absolutely right!!! Saved me!

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, how can I get a JSON object from cypherResponse?

Comment: You should not use this endpoint, it wil be deprecatedsoon. You should use the transactional endpoint -> http://localhost:7474/deb/data/transaction/commit The doc is here -> https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/